# Tailwind responsive is not working using width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind CSS.

I am creating layout using flex. I want to make the right section width `50%` for desktop so I used (`md:w-50`). and I want to use width of `75%` for mobile so I used (`w-75`). the expected behavior for me is small screen will apply width of `75%` and if screen gets bigger `md:w-50` will override the `w-75` – am I understand that right?

I noticed some behavior that I don't understand that `w-75` property has `!important` by default:

[image]

I want to create this:

Desktop(right section width is 50%):
[image]

Mobile(Bottom section width is 75%):
[image]

Classes for section for width:
[image: classes for section for width]

I am getting this,

Desktop:
[image: Desktop]

Mobile:
[image: Mobile]

Width is `75%` whatever screen size is.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here. You can put a sample of your code in a snippet using the editor, and you can load Tailwind via CDN.

Comment: It seems like you either have some custom CSS or some extra Tailwind plugins, since `w-50` and `w-75` by default, do not correspond to `50%` and `75%`. Could you perhaps share more of your Tailwind set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Classes
w-[50%]
w-[75%]
[image]

Comment: Thanks bro, it works. but i don't understand what is the difference between w-50 and w-[50%]. can you explain me this ?